# instance attributes from in __dict__ when subclassing multiple classes

Tags: python, inheritance

I am subclassing from multiple classes. When I print the instance attributes, `self.__dict__` contains only the attributes of the First class. How can I have the attributes of the second included as well?

```
class Third(First,Second):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        print (self.__dict__)
```

Comment: Please show the other classes, First probably does not call super.__init__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `super().__init__` only calls `__init__` from the next superclass in the [*method resolution order*](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html). It is then the role of that next class method to also call `super().__init__`.

### Wrong

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'foo'


class Second:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 'bar'


class Third(First,Second):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.__dict__)

Third() # prints: {'foo': 'foo'}
```

### Right

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'foo'
        super().__init__()


class Second:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 'bar'
        super().__init__()


class Third(First,Second):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.__dict__)

Third() # prints: {'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have omitted the super call `super().__init__()` in `__init__` of class `First`